# Como usar um diretório local como dependência?

Tags: php, composer

Estou desenhando um projeto relativamente grande na minha empresa que é composto por diversas pacotes em PHP. Alguns desses pacotes são pacotes normais e outros são *bundles* de aplicações Symfony.

Quando trabalhamos com Composer, normalmente apontamos o nome de uma dependência o branch ou versão a ser utilizado – entretanto, essa dependência normalmente tem que estar no Github e listada no Packagist. (esse é o fluxo normal, apesar de existirem alternativas)

No meu caso, ainda não quero ter que comitar nenhum código, então as dependências precisam ser diretórios locais. Já defini o arquivo `composer.json` da dependência assim:

```
{
    "name": "rodrigorigotti/shared"
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "RodrigoRigotti": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

E o projeto que contém essa dependência está com o `composer.json` desse jeito:

```
{
    "name": "rodrigorigotti/app",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "/var/www/rodrigorigotti/shared"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "rodrigorigotti/shared": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
}
```

(nota: os arquivos `composer.json` estão BEM simplificados para o propósito da questão)

Entretanto, ao rodar o comando `composer install` ou `composer update` na aplicação que possui a dependência, tenho recebido esse erro:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                        
No driver found to handle VCS repository /var/www/rodrigorigotti/shared
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Eu uso o satis para gerenciar esses pacotes: https://blog.adlermedrado.com.br/configurando-um-reposit%C3%B3rio-privado-usando-composer-e-satis-f7a32fd4f804#.ou1oep27y adiciono o repositório no composer e uso normalmente como se estivesse no packagist. Algumas configurações adicionais no composer podem ser necessárias como:  "config": {
        "secure-http": false,
        "disable-tls": true
    }, caso o satis não esteja em um servidor usando https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dscobri. O diretório a ser usado como dependência precisa ser um projeto Git (`git init`), mesmo eu não esteja em nenhum repositório remoto. Depois basta fazer um commit.

Além disso, deve-se referenciar a branch ou versão correta no `composer.json` do projeto que conterá os outros projetos:

```
{
    "name": "rodrigorigotti/app",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "/var/www/rodrigorigotti/shared"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "rodrigorigotti/shared": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
}
```